# CocoaPods How to add a custom Subclass of a Framework in a Podfile to a CocoaPods framework

Tags: ios, architecture, frameworks, subclass, cocoapods

I am trying to subclass `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from AFNetworking for error handling in an SDK I am creating for an API. The subclasses are created in the Pod/Classes folder in Finder where the other .h and .m files of mine from my CocoaPods framework are stored. The framework was created per this method http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html.

When I attempt to create a new Cocoa Touch Class as a subclass of the aforementioned AFNetworking classes and add its corresponding .h and .m files to the Pods/Classes destination, I get these errors:

```
Ld /Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OSB-iOS-SDK.bundle/OSB-iOS-SDK normal i386
    cd /Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OSB-iOS-SDK.build/Objects-normal/i386/OSB-iOS-SDK.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OSB-iOS-SDK.build/Objects-normal/i386/OSB-iOS-SDK_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bryanboyko/Desktop/XCode/1StudentBody_iOS_Framework/Example/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OSB-iOS-SDK.bundle/OSB-iOS-SDK

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OSBRequestOperation in OSBRequestOperation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OSBRequestOperationManager in OSBRequestOperationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPResponseSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OSBRequestOperation.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OSBRequestOperation in OSBRequestOperation.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OSBRequestOperationManager in OSBRequestOperationManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

If I create the subclasses outside of the Pods target and in the target of an XCode project that I have installed my pods framework in, there are no errors. Because it works in this case, I am assuming that my subclasses in Pod/Classes folder that are a part of my CocoaPods framework do not have access to the AFNetworking framework that is incorporated via the Podfile.

Would love some help!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to be creating subclasses where your CocoaPods are because it could lead to problems when you're installing/updating the pods. Keep the subclass in your own project (after all, it is your own file, not theirs).

If you're trying to create a subclass of a public class in the pod, you can create the subclass in your own project.

If you're trying to create a subclass of a class that's private or internal in the pod, I'd first recommend evaluating whether this is both functionality you want to add and that this is the design pattern you want to use. If you decide yes to both, you should create a fork of the repo, make the changes you want in your fork, then update your Podfile to use your forked version of the pod.